# For every real number $a$ and for every $\epsilon > 0 $ there are infinitely many rationals between $a$ and $a$ + $\epsilon $

Tags: real-analysis

What i'm trying to show is that for every real number $a$, in his $\epsilon$ surrounding i can find infinitely many rationals.  
 If i define set $A=\{ x_0|a<x_0<a+\epsilon\}\bigcup ( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}\{x_n|a<x_n<x_{n-1}\})$ then from density of rationals in $\mathbb R$ every "unionized" set has a member and that member is rational number. Since there are infinitely many members of A,all of them rationals and all of them $a<x_n<a + \epsilon$, $n \in \mathbb N_0$ it follows that there are infinitely many rations for every $\epsilon > 0$ for every real number $a$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Is my proof correct?

Comment: ehm.... no. What is $x_n$??? You may have confused yourself to think you defined some $x_0$, and then go on to define more such things. But you did not. If you think you did, then ask yourself "what is $x_0$"? After you have done that, here is a hint: don't take this approach. Try proof by contradiction.

Comment: I think u have confusion in using density of rationals.

Comment: Try to take $x_0=\frac{a+\epsilon-a}{2}$ that is the mid point...

Comment: @IttayWeiss Could this be good approach. If i assume otherwise i.e. that there are finitely many rationals between $a$ and $a + \epsilon$ then i can find closest the $a$(let's call it x). Then by assumption there are no more rationals between $a$ and $x$. However i know that between any two real numbers $a$ and $x$ there exists rational c such that $a < c < x$, hence a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is another way of proving this...
 Suppose there are only finitely many rationals in between $a$ and $a+\epsilon$, say $x_1,x_2\ldots,x_n$ such that 
$$a<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_n<a+\epsilon$$
Now by density of rationals gives you an rational number between $p$ such that $$a<p<x_1$$ which is a contradiction to our assumption that there are only $n$ rationals between $a$ and $a+\epsilon$.

Comment: thanks.. i changed  the mistake...@rank

Answer (score 0):

For given $n\in \mathbb N$ pick $m\in\mathbb N$ with $m>\frac n\epsilon$. Then the interval $(ma,m(a+\epsilon)$) contains at least $n$ integers $k_1,\ldots, k_n$ because its length is $m\epsilon>n$. Then $(a,a+\epsilon)$ contains the rationals $\frac{k_1}{m},\ldots,\frac{k_n}m$.